# Heroku: temporarily shut down an application

Tags: heroku

I have a heroku application with a corresponding staging application to show improvements before deploying them to production.

Now the size of the database demands a non-dev database with a monthly cost for both.

My question: Is it possible to temporarily shut down the staging application so it can be quickly restarted, but avoiding paying the monthly database cost for the time it is shut down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. Whilst you can set your dyno counts to 0 you pay for the database if it's provisioned.

It might be worth considering your staging environment as a 'throwaway' and remove it when you don't need it and then create a new one when you do, this would be simple to script so it's not too time consuming. Alternatively, do you need a full production dataset for staging? Could you reduce it down instead?

Comment: I will try to do a scripted reduction of the dataset. Thanks!